# How to solve org.testng.TestNGException?

Tags: java, eclipse, testng-eclipse, testng.xml

Why I've got an exception running one TestNG.xml file with eclipse run as TestNGSuite?
But in other TestNG.xml file almost identical doesn't appear the same exception and runs without problem.

Can replicate in IntelliJ, because works correctly in that IDE but not in Eclipse

```
[RemoteTestNG] detected TestNG version 7.5.0
org.testng.TestNGException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:338)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:392)
    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:1040)
    at org.testng.remote.support.RemoteTestNG6_12.initialize(RemoteTestNG6_12.java:22)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:98)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:178)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:400)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1471)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:978)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:541)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:888)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:824)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:141)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1224)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:635)
    at java.xml/com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:324)
    at java.xml/javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:197)
    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:37)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:16)
    at org.testng.xml.SuiteXmlParser.parse(SuiteXmlParser.java:9)
    at org.testng.xml.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:155)
    at org.testng.xml.internal.Parser.parse(Parser.java:241)
    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:326)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end what I did was to make a copy of the TestNG.xml working file and modify the test inside it. But after a few moments return the issue. Just temporary fix

Unless someone could propose a solution for this kind of exception, but I already tried to open with binary editor to see if there were any hidden character at the beginning and found nothing.